# Perl with Catalyst and DBIx::Class - How to load a sets of classes in an inheritance tree?

Tags: perl, inheritance, catalyst, dbix-class

I would like to have a base class Vehicle and most of my system to just use ARRAYs of this type.  With subtypes such as Car, Airplane etc.  When calling a method such as canFly a Car would responsed false, while an Airplane would response true.

I'm planning to use a single DB table (will listen to other suggestions) with a subtype column indicating the actual subclass type and NULL values for the columns used by other sibling subclasses.  How can I at DB query intercept the creation of Vehicle classes and rather given(subclasstype) create the appropriate subclass?
(If this question is not clear I will attempt to clarify better Saturday night (about 28 hrs from now.))

Comment: DBI.pm or DBIx::Class.pm?

Comment: DBIx::Class.pm as indicated in the subject

Comment: I have good days and bad days...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you looking for is called [Dynamic Subclassing](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.082820/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Dynamic_Sub-classing_DBIx::Class_proxy_classes) in DBIx::Class. In Rails/ActiveRecord they call it Single Table Inheritance (STI).

The page to which I've linked is in the [DBIC Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.082820/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod) describes how to override inflate_result so that you can test your row's vehicle type, and then rebless it into the desired subclass.

Answer (score 1):

A conventional constructor looks like:

```
package MyObject;
sub new {
    my ($package, @args) = @_;
    my $self = { };
    ... use @args, initialize $self ...
    return bless $self, $package;    # or sometimes  bless $self,__PACKAGE__
}
```

It is the `bless` statement that assigns a "type" to the data structure in `$self`. Usually, the second argument to `bless` is the name of the current package. But this is Perl, so you don't always have to do things the usual way. Even in the constructor for `MyObject`, you don't have to pass `MyObject` to `bless`:

```
package MyObject;
sub new {
    my ($package, %args) = @_;
    my $self = { };
    ... use @args, initialize $self ...
    if ($args{"type"} == 1)    { $package = "MyObject::Foo"; }
    elsif ($args{"type"} == 2) { $package = "MyObject::Bar"; }
    elsif ($args{"type"} == 3) { ... }
    return bless $self, $package;
}
```